# Splitting a word into characters VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox of maxLength 8. the 1st two characters must be "PM" or "00". I tried split(), but didnt work.

Comment: Where is your code? Input examples, expected versus actual results? Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and [edit] your question

Answer (score 1):

Use [substring()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-vbnet) method

```
    Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text.Substring(0, 2)

    If s = "PM" Or s = "00" Then
        MessageBox.Show("good!")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("bad!")
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use `StartsWith()`

```
If TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("PM") OR TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("00") Then
    'Do something
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use regular expressions:

```
Dim re As New Regex("PM|00")
If re.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text) Then
  'do something
End If
```

The benefit is that when you decide what to do with the other 6 characters, you can modify the above to capture and return those (in full or part), without having to rewrite your code. You can even process multiple occurrences of `PM|00` in one string and capture them all.

Useful resource, a Regex sandbox:

- https://www.regex101.com/

Comment: Just came back to add this to my answer.  This would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
if textbox1.text like "PM*" or textbox1.text like "00*" then
   Do something
else msgbox("You don't have pm or 00  to start with!")
end if
```

Comment: You need to replace `=` with `Like` for this to work.